# Dealing with daylight savings on date objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, utc

I'm having a hard time understanding how to deal with clock changes when Daylight Saving starts and ends in the UK.

So say I create an appointment entry in a front end web app with a start time for today at 14:30, and lets say the component for choosing a date time returns a native date object for the start time like so

> Thu Jun 02 2016 14:30:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)

I would then need to save as UTC to the database and so the above date in UTC ISO8601 format would be `2016-06-02T13:30:00:000Z`

When Daylight Savings ends in UK, the time zone will become GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time). Parsing the UTC stored string `2016-06-02T13:30:00:000Z` back into a Date object for display client side will give back (I think)

> Thu Jun 02 2016 13:30:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)

Have I got that correct, because if so, how do I get back the hour lost as it should be 14:30 so the entry appears correct on the front end app. Should additional offset information be included when saving the date into an ISO string?

I'll probably have a face palm moment when someone comments on this!

Thanks

Comment: A date+time combination is either affected by local daylight savings time, or it is not; that won't change. If somebody schedules something for 14:30 on some particular date, then it is scheduled for that time on that date, even if the date is *looked at* from a point in time that is differently affected by daylight savings.

Comment: In other words, the date matters. Regardless of the *current* state of daylight savings time, a date-time is rendered into locale-sensitive display format according to the rules *for that date*, not the current date.

Comment: Ah ok, so in my example, I look at that saved date in UK winter when daylight savings are not in effect, but because the saved date had daylight savings applied it gets displayed correctly through native browser JS?

Comment: Right - if it's a date in the winter when daylight savings is *not* in effect, then it will be shown according to those rules (no daylight savings) regardless of the *current* date.

Comment: Yup ok, took reading them comments a few times but I follow. Thanks!

Comment: Note also that time zone offsets and changes for daylight saving are only applied based on the host system settings. Date objects themselves don't have an offset, the host does. And the current settings are assumed to have applied always (e.g. start on last Sunday in March), so historical changes aren't accounted for.

Comment: I've read the comments but I'm still a little unclear - when creating a JS date from UTC milliseconds, the browser looks at the date and decides for itself whether or not to adjust for daylight savings? So we as developers don't actually have to do anything regarding the +0100? We have some code to parse UTC dates which contains a bug where British Summer Time dates have an extra hour added, I think due to this behaviour. But Group Policy prevents me from altering my work station system date so I'm unable to test what the behaviour would be once we revert to GMT!